# Removing auto complete in odoo14

Tags: odoo-14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDw10.png)

How to remove this auto name_search such as customers when we create an invoice as shown in the above picture link & stop fetching data from external API in Odoo 14?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **remove** *Partner Autocomplete* from **General settings**

[image: Partner Autocomplete in Settings]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69207915/16916235 Can you please help me with this question too?